# Discrete cosine transform and histogram equalisation

Tags: computer-vision, dct, image-compression, jpeg

I found an image hash library for python and [this blog](https://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html)

In the block *Getting Funky With pHash*, the author writes:

> Further reduce the DCT. This is the magic step. Set the 64 hash bits
> to 0 or 1 depending on whether each of the 64 DCT values is above or
> below the average value. The result doesn't tell us the actual low
> frequencies; it just tells us the very-rough relative scale of the
> frequencies to the mean. The result will not vary as long as the
> overall structure of the image remains the same; this can survive
> gamma and color histogram adjustments without a problem.

Histogram equalization changes frequencies of pixel values.
Could you explain why histogram equalization does not affect coefficients?

Comment: why should it or shouldn't it? in the quote I see no claims referring to *histogram equalization*.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz histogram equalisation doesn't relate with histogram adjustments?

Comment: how does _that_ relate to DCT?